# Sort cpt by custom taxonomy first, then the rest of post

Tags: wordpress, sorting, filter, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to display the 3 most recent posts from a custom post type vacancies.
But is there are any posts with the custom taxonomy "option" value equal to "featured", then they should show first.

So if 2x post is tagged "featured" then they will show first and then just the most recent post.
Below code will only show posts tagged "featured" but if there are only 1 or 2 posts tagged featured, I won't get to 3 posts.

Any advice will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

```
`$loop_args = array (
'post_type' => 'vacancies',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'tax_query' => array(
   array(
  'taxonomy' => 'option',
  'field' => 'slug',
  'terms' => 'featured'
 )
 )
);
$custom_loop = new WP_Query( $loop_args );
while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();

$intro = get_field( 'vacancy_introduction' );
$area = get_field( 'vacancy_area' );

<?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );?>
<h3>
  <?php if( $area ): ?>
  <?php echo $area; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</h3>
<div>
  <?php if( $intro ): ?>
  <?php echo $intro; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<a class="morex" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><button><?php _e('Read More', 'tsum'); ?></button></a>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add after your initial loop. (after your endwhile)

But remove your `wp_reset_query` so you can still access the count.

```
<?php
$count = $custom_loop->found_posts;
if ($count < 3){
    $show = $count - 3;
    $second_loop = array (
        'post_type' => 'vacancies',
        'posts_per_page' => $show,
        'tax_query' => array(
           array(
              'taxonomy'    => 'option',
              'field'       => 'slug',
              'terms'       => 'featured',
              'operator'    => 'NOT IN',
                )
            )
        );

    $custom2 = new WP_Query($second_loop);

    while ( $custom2->have_posts() ) : $custom2->the_post();

    $intro = get_field( 'vacancy_introduction' );
    $area = get_field( 'vacancy_area' ); ?>

    <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );?>
    <h3>
      <?php if( $area ): ?>
      <?php echo $area; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <?php if( $intro ): ?>
      <?php echo $intro; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <a class="morex" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><button><?php _e('Read More', 'tsum'); ?></button></a>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not simple query to list results sorted with taxonomy. You should fetch first all taxonomy array and then use foreach loop for each taxonomy to get all post result, like this:

```
   $styles = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'style',
        'fields' => 'ids',   //get the IDs only         
        'orderby' => 'tax_position',
        'hide_empty'   => true,
    ));

foreach($styles as $style){

$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'hotels',
     'posts_per_page' => 20,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC'),
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'paged' => $paged,
     'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'style',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $style,
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                    ) 
     );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          get_template_part( 'templates/style', 'page' );
  endwhile`enter code here`; // End the loop.

} //end foreach
```